# marquee without gap

Tags: html

[link text](http://eltech.tv/)

in the right side, there is a block TOP SELLER,

for this block i used the marquee tag,

How to remove the gap at the end of loop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I verified with firebug the list continues to scroll up until the last item is finished thus the space. So my suggestion is to make the list twice thus when one is done the other one follows underneath the other and so on.